# Funcao retornando warning open_basedir restriction in effect. File

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, warnings

tenho uma função em PHP que verifica se tenho novos pedidos no sistema. se tiver com o retorno em ajax eu exibo uma notificação toas exibido o numero do pedido.

Função PHP **verificaNovoPedido.php**

```
<?php
include('../../class/mysql_crud.php');

$pedido = 0;


$db = new Database();
$db->connect();
$db->sql("SELECT * FROM lanc_pedidos WHERE status='1' and notificado='0'");
$res = $db->numRows();
    if ($res >= 1){
      $res = $db->getResult();
      foreach ($res as $output) {
        $pedido = $output["guid"];
      }

 $db->update('lanc_pedidos', array('notificado'=>1), 'guid='.$pedido);
 $res = $db->getResult();
 } else {
   $pedido = 0;
 }

if ($pedido > 10){
  echo 0;
} else {
  echo ($pedido);
}
```

Função Ajax

```
var timeout = setTimeout(verificaNovoPedido, 2000);
function verificaNovoPedido(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "ajax/pedidos/verificaNovoPedido.php",
    type: "POST",
    success: function (dados){
      if (dados != 0){
        notifyMe(dados);
        reloadtableAllPedido();
      }
    }
  })
  timeout = setTimeout(verificaNovoPedido, 2000);
}
```

O **Problema** é que as vezes retornando um warning, no caso isto:

> Pedido Recebido, Num: 
> ↵**Warning**:  include() [function.include]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/u312527797/public_html/painel/class/mysql_crud.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/u702782028:/tmp:/var/tmp:/opt/php-5.3/pear:/usr/local/bin) in **/home/u312527797/public_html/painel/ajax/pedidos/verificaNovoPedido.php** on line **2**
> ↵
> ↵**Warning**:  include(/home/u312527797/public_html/painel/class/mysql_crud.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in **/home/u312527797/public_html/painel/ajax/pedidos/verificaNovoPedido.php** on line **2**
> ↵
> ↵**Warning**:  include() [function.include]: Failed opening '../../class/mysql_crud.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php-5.3/pear') in **/home/u312527797/public_html/painel/ajax/pedidos/verificaNovoPedido.php** on line **2**
> ↵
> ↵**Fatal error**:  Class 'Database' not found in **/home/u312527797/public_html/painel/ajax/pedidos/verificaNovoPedido.php** on line **7**
> ↵ para visualizar clique ↵**Warning**:  include() [function.include]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/u312527797/public_html/painel/class/mysql_crud.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/u702782028:/tmp:/var/tmp:/opt/php-5.3/pear:/usr/local/bin) in **/home/u312527797/public_html/painel/ajax/pedidos/verificaNovoPedido.php** on line **2**
> ↵
> ↵**Warning**:  include(/home/u312527797/public_html/painel/class/mysql_crud.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in **/home/u312527797/public_html/painel/ajax/pedidos/verificaNovoPedido.php** on line **2**
> ↵
> ↵**Warning**:  include() [function.include]: Failed opening '../../class/mysql_crud.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php-5.3/pear') in **/home/u312527797/public_html/painel/ajax/pedidos/verificaNovoPedido.php** on line **2**
> ↵
> ↵**Fatal error**:  Class 'Database' not found in **/home/u312527797/public_html/painel/ajax/pedidos/verificaNovoPedido.php** on line **7**
> ↵);' class='btn btn-outline-info btn-sm'>Aqui

Alguém poderia me ajudar a resolver este problema ?
Obrigaod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edite o seu arquivo httpd.conf ( /etc/httpd/httpd.conf ).
Procure "open_basedir" e defina ele como "none" (php_admin_value open_basedir none)

Na sua linha 2 o include falha e isso gera uma série de erros.

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11233478/2467235)

Comment: consigo fazer isso via putty ?

Comment: Sim, se você editar o arquivo usando o vi ou o vim. Você também precisa saber em que pasta o arquivo httpd.conf está localizado, porque isso varia de acordo com a localização do apache.

Comment: para editar um arquivo com o vi/ vim pelo putty você pode usar sudo vim /endereco/do/arquivo.txt. Você está usando windows ou linux? tem alguns clientes que facilitam o acesso aos arquivos.

Comment: estou usando windows, mas nao sei se a hospedagem que estou utilizando da permissão para ir até estes arquivos

Comment: Já que a hospedagem é compartilhada, provavelmente não! O jeito vai ser mover o arquivo chamado pelo include (ou uma cópia dele) para uma pasta que você tenha permissão de leitura.

Comment: certo, o estranho que funciona a funcao. apenas de vez enquando acontece esse problema. coisa de duas em duas horas

Comment: Como você não é o administrador do servidor o jeito vai ser abrir um ticket com a sua hospedagem.

Comment: conversei com eles agora pouco. disseram que não é possivel alterar tais configurações...  o que eu fiz foi nao exibir o erro. eu sei que é retornado apenas o guid do pedido que nao vai ter uma extensao grande. eu comparei tamanhos e so exibo a notificaçao quando realmente for um pedido. assim nao ira exibir o erro na tela pelo menos